# MS Chart for .NET predefined palettes color list?

Tags: asp.net, mschart, color-palette

Microsoft Chart for .NET (3.5, 4.x) has predefined palettes e.g. Berry, Bright, SeaGreen etc.

Is there anywhere a list of colors for each palette (hex or named)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found this image on [Alex Gorev's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx)

[image: Predefined palettes of MS Chart]

Guess I can use color picker to get actual color names/codes

**EDIT:** Here are the list of colors I extracted:

```
Berry: 8A2BE2,BA55D3,4169E1,C71585,0000FF,8019E0,DA70D6,7B68EE,C000C0,0000CD,800080
Bright: 008000,0000FF,800080,800080,FF00FF,008080,FFFF00,808080,00FFFF,000080,800000,FF3939,7F7F00,C0C0C0,FF6347,FFE4B5
BrightPastel: 418CF0,FCB441,DF3A02,056492,BFBFBF,1A3B69,FFE382,129CDD,CA6B4B,005CDB,F3D288,506381,F1B9A8,E0830A,7893BE
Chocolate: A0522D,D2691E,8B0000,CD853F,A52A2A,F4A460,8B4513,C04000,B22222,B65C3A
EarthTones: 33023,B8860B,C04000,6B8E23,CD853F,C0C000,228B22,D2691E,808000,20B2AA,F4A460,00C000,8FBC8B,B22222,843A05,C00000
Excel: 9999FF,993366,FFFFCC,CCFFFF,660066,FF8080,0063CB,CCCCFF,000080,FF00FF,FFFF00,00FFFF,800080,800000,007F7F,0000FF
Fire: FFD700,FF0000,FF1493,DC143C,FF8C00,FF00FF,FFFF00,FF4500,C71585,DDE221
GrayScale: C8C8C8,BDBDBD,B2B2B2,A7A7A7,9C9C9C,919191,868686,7A7A7A,707070,656565,565656,4F4F4F,424242,393939,2E2E2E,232323
Light: E6E6FA,FFF0F5,FFDAB9,,FFFACD,,FFE4E1,F0FFF0,F0F8FF,F5F5F5,FAEBD7,E0FFFF
Pastel: 87CEEB,32CD32,BA55D3,F08080,4682B4,9ACD32,40E0D0,FF69B4,F0E68C,D2B48C,8FBC8B,6495ED,DDA0DD,5F9EA0,FFDAB9,FFA07A
SeaGreen: 2E8B57,66CDAA,4682B4,008B8B,5F9EA0,38B16E,48D1CC,B0C4DE,8FBC8B,87CEEB
SemiTransparent: FF6969,69FF69,6969FF,FFFF5D,69FFFF,FF69FF,CDB075,FFAFAF,AFFFAF,AFAFFF,FFFFAF,AFFFFF,FFAFFF,E4D5B5,A4B086,819EC1
```

Comment: After you extract the names/colors you should definitely come back and post them here.

Comment: @GabrielBB no problem. Glad the information was useful.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Hey thanks for posting this.  The colors are also available now from Microsoft's reference source.  Check it out: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web.DataVisualization/Common/Utilities/ColorPalette.cs

Answer (score 10):

I Created an Extension class that returns a List of colors for the pallet.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;

namespace Extensions.Colors {
    public static class ChartColorPallets   {

        public static List<Color> Bright 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#008000".FromHex(),
                "#0000FF".FromHex(),
                "#800080".FromHex(),
                "#00FF00".FromHex(),
                "#FF00FF".FromHex(),
                "#008080".FromHex(),
                "#FFFF00".FromHex(),
                "#808080".FromHex(),
                "#00FFFF".FromHex(),
                "#000080".FromHex(),
                "#800000".FromHex(),
                "#FF0000".FromHex(),
                "#808000".FromHex(),
                "#C0C0C0".FromHex(),
                "#FF6347".FromHex(),
                "#FFE4B5".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> GreyScale 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#C8C8C8".FromHex(),
                "#BDBDBD".FromHex(),
                "#B2B2B2".FromHex(),
                "#A7A7A7".FromHex(),
                "#9C9C9C".FromHex(),
                "#919191".FromHex(),
                "#868686".FromHex(),
                "#7B7B7B".FromHex(),
                "#707070".FromHex(),
                "#656565".FromHex(),
                "#5A5A5A".FromHex(),
                "#4F4F4F".FromHex(),
                "#444444".FromHex(),
                "#393939".FromHex(),
                "#2E2E2E".FromHex(),
                "#232323".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Excel 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#9999FF".FromHex(),
                "#993366".FromHex(),
                "#FFFFCC".FromHex(),
                "#CCFFFF".FromHex(),
                "#660066".FromHex(),
                "#FF8080".FromHex(),
                "#0066CC".FromHex(),
                "#CCCCFF".FromHex(),
                "#000080".FromHex(),
                "#FF00FF".FromHex(),
                "#FFFF00".FromHex(),
                "#00FFFF".FromHex(),
                "#800080".FromHex(),
                "#800000".FromHex(),
                "#008080".FromHex(),
                "#0000FF".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Light 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#E6E6FA".FromHex(),
                "#FFF0F5".FromHex(),
                "#FFDAB9".FromHex(),
                "#FFFACD".FromHex(),
                "#FFE4E1".FromHex(),
                "#F0FFF0".FromHex(),
                "#F0F8FF".FromHex(),
                "#F5F5F5".FromHex(),
                "#FAEBD7".FromHex(),
                "#E0FFFF".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Pastel 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#87CEEB".FromHex(),
                "#32CD32".FromHex(),
                "#BA55D3".FromHex(),
                "#F08080".FromHex(),
                "#4682B4".FromHex(),
                "#9ACD32".FromHex(),
                "#40E0D0".FromHex(),
                "#FF69B4".FromHex(),
                "#F0E68C".FromHex(),
                "#D2B48C".FromHex(),
                "#8FBC8B".FromHex(),
                "#6495ED".FromHex(),
                "#DDA0DD".FromHex(),
                "#5F9EA0".FromHex(),
                "#FFDAB9".FromHex(),
                "#FFA07A".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> EarthTones 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#FF8000".FromHex(),
                "#B8860B".FromHex(),
                "#C04000".FromHex(),
                "#6B8E23".FromHex(),
                "#CD853F".FromHex(),
                "#C0C000".FromHex(),
                "#228B22".FromHex(),
                "#D2691E".FromHex(),
                "#808000".FromHex(),
                "#20B2AA".FromHex(),
                "#F4A460".FromHex(),
                "#00C000".FromHex(),
                "#8FBC8B".FromHex(),
                "#B22222".FromHex(),
                "#8B4513".FromHex(),
                "#C00000".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> SemiTransparent 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#FF0000".FromHex(),
                "#00FF00".FromHex(),
                "#0000FF".FromHex(),
                "#FFFF00".FromHex(),
                "#00FFFF".FromHex(),
                "#FF00FF".FromHex(),
                "#AA7814".FromHex(),
                "#FF0000".FromHex(),
                "#00FF00".FromHex(),
                "#0000FF".FromHex(),
                "#FFFF00".FromHex(),
                "#00FFFF".FromHex(),
                "#FF00FF".FromHex(),
                "#AA7814".FromHex(),
                "#647832".FromHex(),
                "#285A96".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Berry
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#8A2BE2".FromHex(),
                "#BA55D3".FromHex(),
                "#4169E1".FromHex(),
                "#C71585".FromHex(),
                "#0000FF".FromHex(),
                "#8A2BE2".FromHex(),
                "#DA70D6".FromHex(),
                "#7B68EE".FromHex(),
                "#C000C0".FromHex(),
                "#0000CD".FromHex(),
                "#800080".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Chocolate 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#A0522D".FromHex(),
                "#D2691E".FromHex(),
                "#8B0000".FromHex(),
                "#CD853F".FromHex(),
                "#A52A2A".FromHex(),
                "#F4A460".FromHex(),
                "#8B4513".FromHex(),
                "#C04000".FromHex(),
                "#B22222".FromHex(),
                "#B65C3A".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> Fire
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#FFD700".FromHex(),
                "#FF0000".FromHex(),
                "#FF1493".FromHex(),
                "#DC143C".FromHex(),
                "#FF8C00".FromHex(),
                "#FF00FF".FromHex(),
                "#FFFF00".FromHex(),
                "#FF4500".FromHex(),
                "#C71585".FromHex(),
                "#DDE221".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> SeaGreen 
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#2E8B57".FromHex(),
                "#66CDAA".FromHex(),
                "#4682B4".FromHex(),
                "#008B8B".FromHex(),
                "#5F9EA0".FromHex(),
                "#3CB371".FromHex(),
                "#48D1CC".FromHex(),
                "#B0C4DE".FromHex(),
                "#8FBC8B".FromHex(),
                "#87CEEB".FromHex()
        };
        public static List<Color> BrightPastel
            => new List<Color>() {
                "#418CF0".FromHex(),
                "#FCB441".FromHex(),
                "#E0400A".FromHex(),
                "#056492".FromHex(),
                "#BFBFBF".FromHex(),
                "#1A3B69".FromHex(),
                "#FFE382".FromHex(),
                "#129CDD".FromHex(),
                "#CA6B4B".FromHex(),
                "#005CDB".FromHex(),
                "#F3D288".FromHex(),
                "#506381".FromHex(),
                "#F1B9A8".FromHex(),
                "#E0830A".FromHex(),
                "#7893BE".FromHex()
        };
        private static Color FromHex(this string hex) => ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the list of colors, just include the namespace, then you can call

```
List<Color> brightColors = ChartColorPallets.Bright;
```

Answer (score 5):

+1 to Yuriy's answer, but if you are looking for the EXACT colors (33023 is not a valid color, among other bad matches), I extracted them here from the actual values:

```
Bright: "#008000", "#0000FF", "#800080", "#00FF00", "#FF00FF", "#008080", "#FFFF00", "#808080", "#00FFFF", "#000080", "#800000", "#FF0000", "#808000", "#C0C0C0", "#FF6347", "#FFE4B5"
Grayscale: "#C8C8C8", "#BDBDBD", "#B2B2B2", "#A7A7A7", "#9C9C9C", "#919191", "#868686", "#7B7B7B", "#707070", "#656565", "#5A5A5A", "#4F4F4F", "#444444", "#393939", "#2E2E2E", "#232323"
Excel: "#9999FF", "#993366", "#FFFFCC", "#CCFFFF", "#660066", "#FF8080", "#0066CC", "#CCCCFF", "#000080", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#800080", "#800000", "#008080", "#0000FF"
Light: "#E6E6FA", "#FFF0F5", "#FFDAB9", "#FFFACD", "#FFE4E1", "#F0FFF0", "#F0F8FF", "#F5F5F5", "#FAEBD7", "#E0FFFF"
Pastel: "#87CEEB", "#32CD32", "#BA55D3", "#F08080", "#4682B4", "#9ACD32", "#40E0D0", "#FF69B4", "#F0E68C", "#D2B48C", "#8FBC8B", "#6495ED", "#DDA0DD", "#5F9EA0", "#FFDAB9", "#FFA07A"
EarthTones: "#FF8000", "#B8860B", "#C04000", "#6B8E23", "#CD853F", "#C0C000", "#228B22", "#D2691E", "#808000", "#20B2AA", "#F4A460", "#00C000", "#8FBC8B", "#B22222", "#8B4513", "#C00000"
SemiTransparent: "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#AA7814", "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#AA7814", "#647832", "#285A96"
Berry: "#8A2BE2", "#BA55D3", "#4169E1", "#C71585", "#0000FF", "#8A2BE2", "#DA70D6", "#7B68EE", "#C000C0", "#0000CD", "#800080"
Chocolate: "#A0522D", "#D2691E", "#8B0000", "#CD853F", "#A52A2A", "#F4A460", "#8B4513", "#C04000", "#B22222", "#B65C3A"
Fire: "#FFD700", "#FF0000", "#FF1493", "#DC143C", "#FF8C00", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00", "#FF4500", "#C71585", "#DDE221"
SeaGreen: "#2E8B57", "#66CDAA", "#4682B4", "#008B8B", "#5F9EA0", "#3CB371", "#48D1CC", "#B0C4DE", "#8FBC8B", "#87CEEB"
BrightPastel: "#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF", "#1A3B69", "#FFE382", "#129CDD", "#CA6B4B", "#005CDB", "#F3D288", "#506381", "#F1B9A8", "#E0830A", "#7893BE"
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time trying to find this same information a while back and never found the answer.

I eventually had to "discover" the values myself. I only needed the BrighPastel Color Palette, and this is what I found:

```
'See Color Palette details here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx
Public BrightPastel_ColorPalette As Integer() = {15764545, 4306172, 671968, 9593861, 12566463, 6896410, 8578047, 14523410, 4942794, 14375936, 8966899, 8479568, 11057649, 689120, 12489592}
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

With the open sourcing of .NET, you can find all of the chart palette colors here:

https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/Utilities/ColorPalette.cs

Answer (score 1):

I can't be the only one that wanted to be able to see this on a web page.  So here is some quick and dirty VB.NET code to display this.  Just put a literal on the page called 'LitColors'.

Hope this saves someone 30 minutes.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ArrBright() As String = {"#008000", "#0000FF", "#800080", "#00FF00", "#FF00FF", "#008080", "#FFFF00", "#808080", "#00FFFF", "#000080", "#800000", "#FF0000", "#808000", "#C0C0C0", "#FF6347", "#FFE4B5"}
    Dim ArrGrayscale() As String = {"#C8C8C8", "#BDBDBD", "#B2B2B2", "#A7A7A7", "#9C9C9C", "#919191", "#868686", "#7B7B7B", "#707070", "#656565", "#5A5A5A", "#4F4F4F", "#444444", "#393939", "#2E2E2E", "#232323"}
    Dim ArrExcel() As String = {"#9999FF", "#993366", "#FFFFCC", "#CCFFFF", "#660066", "#FF8080", "#0066CC", "#CCCCFF", "#000080", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#800080", "#800000", "#008080", "#0000FF"}
    Dim ArrLight() As String = {"#E6E6FA", "#FFF0F5", "#FFDAB9", "#FFFACD", "#FFE4E1", "#F0FFF0", "#F0F8FF", "#F5F5F5", "#FAEBD7", "#E0FFFF"}
    Dim ArrPastel() As String = {"#87CEEB", "#32CD32", "#BA55D3", "#F08080", "#4682B4", "#9ACD32", "#40E0D0", "#FF69B4", "#F0E68C", "#D2B48C", "#8FBC8B", "#6495ED", "#DDA0DD", "#5F9EA0", "#FFDAB9", "#FFA07A"}
    Dim ArrEarthTones() As String = {"#FF8000", "#B8860B", "#C04000", "#6B8E23", "#CD853F", "#C0C000", "#228B22", "#D2691E", "#808000", "#20B2AA", "#F4A460", "#00C000", "#8FBC8B", "#B22222", "#8B4513", "#C00000"}
    Dim ArrSemiTransparent() As String = {"#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#AA7814", "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#AA7814", "#647832", "#285A96"}
    Dim ArrBerry() As String = {"#8A2BE2", "#BA55D3", "#4169E1", "#C71585", "#0000FF", "#8A2BE2", "#DA70D6", "#7B68EE", "#C000C0", "#0000CD", "#800080"}
    Dim ArrChocolate() As String = {"#A0522D", "#D2691E", "#8B0000", "#CD853F", "#A52A2A", "#F4A460", "#8B4513", "#C04000", "#B22222", "#B65C3A"}
    Dim ArrFire() As String = {"#FFD700", "#FF0000", "#FF1493", "#DC143C", "#FF8C00", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00", "#FF4500", "#C71585", "#DDE221"}
    Dim ArrSeaGreen() As String = {"#2E8B57", "#66CDAA", "#4682B4", "#008B8B", "#5F9EA0", "#3CB371", "#48D1CC", "#B0C4DE", "#8FBC8B", "#87CEEB"}
    Dim ArrBrightPastel() As String = {"#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF", "#1A3B69", "#FFE382", "#129CDD", "#CA6B4B", "#005CDB", "#F3D288", "#506381", "#F1B9A8", "#E0830A", "#7893BE"}

    Dim HTML As String = ""
    HTML = HTML & "<table>"


    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Bright</td>"
    For Each a In ArrBright
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>GrayScale</td>"
    For Each a In ArrGrayscale
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Excel</td>"
    For Each a In ArrExcel
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Light</td>"
    For Each a In ArrLight
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Pastel</td>"
    For Each a In ArrPastel
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>EarthTomes</td>"
    For Each a In ArrEarthTones
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Semi Transparent</td>"
    For Each a In ArrSemiTransparent
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Berry</td>"
    For Each a In ArrBerry
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Chocolate</td>"
    For Each a In ArrChocolate
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>Fire</td>"
    For Each a In ArrFire
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>SeaGreen</td>"
    For Each a In ArrSeaGreen
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "<tr>"
    HTML = HTML & "<td>BrightPastel</td>"
    For Each a In ArrBrightPastel
        HTML = HTML & "<td style=""background: " & a.ToString & " "" >" & a.ToString & "</td>"
    Next
    HTML = HTML & "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"

    HTML = HTML & "</table>"

    LitColors.Text = HTML
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation looking at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239355(v=sql.100).aspx

it a set of regular used Microsoft color codes 
all this list of them can be found here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531197.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. If you take a look at actual palette (list of colors) e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx (oh and it's for ASP.NET not for reports), I need a list of specific colors for each named palette, e.g: "Berry = 00FF22, 2211DE, ...."