# What algorithm to use to convert one letter to color Gmail-style?

Tags: c#, listview, user-interface

In some email applications, list items are shown as 'cards', every which of them have a big round icon with the first letter of the header text. The conversion is stable - every letter converted to the same color every time (numbers of colors and letters may not match). I think, it may greatly improve visual and navigation.

I can hardcode color values for every letter to some kind of a dictionary. But I want to get colors (those similar to Google's) based on letter code to avoid hardcoding.

So, the question is - what algorithm to use to get Gmail-like colors from letters.

Any programming language is acceptable for solution, but C# is more preferable.

It will be great if the algorithm will cover any char, not only latin alphabet symbols, but maybe cyrillic ones and some special characters (like @, #, $, %, etc.)

Attaching a sample from my own account.

[image: sample]

Comment: What's your exact question here? One different color for each letter? Define an array that holds all the letters and a coresponding hex code then.

Comment: You should try first and come back when you've got some code, even not working, to show us.

Comment: Example with code: http://randomstringtocsscolor.com/

Comment: Exact question is how to get color based on letter's char code. AND, if possible, get colors from similar palette as Google did.

Comment: There are a million possibilities to do this. Colors are defined in HEX. Based on the string you enter, you should calculate a color. How you do this is how you want. Convert each letter to a integer value and add those to get an RGB color, predefined color values for each letter and mixing them up, ...

Comment: There is no such function to convert a char code to a color. You should do this yourself based on how you would like to do it.

Comment: @Alexander, great! But unfortunately it gives me the same color for every letter. I think it is because the algorithm is pointed to generate from string properties, not from char code.

Comment: That's exately the point, you should define your own algorithm on how you would like to do it. If you don't want that, then your question should be 'What algorithm to use for ...'

Comment: I'm trying something, please be patient.

Comment: I guess that Google does it with hardcoded colors :)

Comment: Also come up with the question. The color definitely depends not only on letter (try to create many contacts with the same first letter -- they will have different colors). Probably it depends on _id or contactUri, to stay stable, though exact algorithm is still a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static Color ToColorFromTitleCaseLetters(this string fullName)
    {
        if (fullName.IsNullOrEmpty()) return Color.Blue;

        try
        {
            string result = string.Concat(Regex
                .Matches(fullName, "[A-Z]")
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(match => match.Value));

            int hash = 1;
            if (result.Length > 1)
            {
                hash = (Convert.ToInt32(result[0]) - 64) * 100 + Convert.ToInt32(result[1]) - 64; 


                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204827/ms-chart-for-net-predefined-palettes-color-list
                string[] colors = new[]
                {
                    "008000", "0000FF", "800080", "800080", "FF00FF", "008080", "FFFF00", "808080", "00FFFF",
                    "000080",
                    "800000", "FF3939", "7F7F00", "C0C0C0", "FF6347", "FFE4B5", "33023", "B8860B", "C04000",
                    "6B8E23", "CD853F", "C0C000", "228B22", "D2691E", "808000", "20B2AA", "F4A460", "00C000",
                    "8FBC8B", "B22222", "843A05", "C00000"
                };

                int max = (('Z' - 64) * 100 + 'Z' - 64);

                decimal index = ((decimal) hash / (decimal) max) * colors.Length;
                return Color.FromHex(colors[(int) index]);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return Color.Blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple algorithm, please note that you should adapt it on how you would like it to function:

First, I'll take a character, get the ASCII code from it.
Then I'll make sure that it's 3 numbers by adding zeroes before.
Then that value and the value before and after it are used as the RGB colors.

Here's the code:

```
Console.Write("Please enter a given character: ");
var characterCode = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar).ToString();

Console.WriteLine("");

// Convert integer 182 as a hex in a string variable
string characterRColor = characterCode.PadLeft(3, '0');
string characterGColor = (Convert.ToInt32(characterCode) - 1).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
string characterBColor = (Convert.ToInt32(characterCode) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');

Console.WriteLine("R Color: " + characterRColor);
Console.WriteLine("G Color: " + characterGColor);
Console.WriteLine("B Color: " + characterBColor);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: May be a good point to start with, but not working - all the colors are just grey with various luminance. Breaks if the KeyChar is greater than byte's limit.

Comment: That's why I've told you earlier that you should come up with al algorithm yourself. We don't know what you want. Only a selective of 5 different colors, or a different color for every letter. Maybe 5 colors with different tints for every letter...